# How to change brightness in Windows XP without built-in keyboard?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, display, brightness, display-settings

I have broken keyboard on my MSI EX-600 so I can't press "function buttons" to change brightness, volume, etc. Is it possible to change brightness of display (not graphic card!) without the keyboard in Windows XP? This is my nb: http://www.msi.com/product/nb/EX600.html

Comment: broken means you are not able to use any of the keys or just some of the keys?

Comment: It's been awhile since I had access to XP, but those settings are typically available through the control panel (and volume is also available through an icon on the system tray).  The controls on function keys aren't physical controls, they are more like pre-programmed "macros" that send a command.  So if the button gets damaged, you are just losing a convenience.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.nelsonpires.com/software/dimmer/

This small executable once used will instantly dim the screen. You can find it in the system tray to further configure it to be more or less dim. I found this after Googling because my function keys were not working on my laptop and there was no other way to reduce brightness in windows XP. I thought there had to be an external program made by a 3rd party.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The asker wants to set the backlight brightness, not dim the screen.